# Запрос на выборку к 4-ем таблицам (sql)

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Есть запрос в БД который я не могу нормально сформулировать(что бы адекватно работал).  Есть таблица orders в которой стоят id заказчиков, и есть еще две таблицы: customers и firms для которых делался заказ (m-t-m через еще одну таблицу groups, где стоят id фирм и заказчиков). Мне нужно выбрать заказчиков у которых самое большое количество заказов и связанных с ним фирм и отсортировать по количеству(заказов) в порядке убывания... пока бьюсь безуспешно. Кто-то может подсказать?

Orders
|id|sum|date|customer_id|

Customers
|id|name|last_name|e_mail|

Firms
|id|name|e_mail|

Groups
|customer_id|firm_id|

На выходе должно быть:
Firms.name Customers.name COUNT(количество заказов данного Сustomers.name)

Тоесть этот клиент имеет наибольшее количество заказов в общем и имя фирмы, с которой идет наибольшее количество связей в Groups, потому как один клиент, может заказывать для разных фирм и принадлежать к разным фирмам.

Comment: Кто-нибудь понял из вопроса структуру базы вопрошающего?

Comment: если я правильно понял то последняя таблица - `groups` - это `mapping` (N to N) между `customer` и `firms`

Comment: Приведите в вопросе какой именно диалект SQL используется. Укажите точную структуру всех таблиц, запрос который у вас уже получился и что вы хотите получить на выходе (чем отличается выход вашего запроса от требуемого)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать что-то вроде этого:

```
select 
    c.c_id  as "customer id",
    ord.cnt as "orders count",
    frm.cnt as "firms count"
  from c
  left outer join (select c_id, count(*) as cnt from o group by c_id) ord on c.c_id = ord.c_id
  left outer join (select c_id, count(*) as cnt from g group by c_id) frm on c.c_id = frm.c_id
  order by 
    ord.cnt desc nulls last,
    frm.cnt desc nulls last
```

где `c, o, g` - таблицы с заказчиками, заказами и связями заказчиков с фирмами (`groups`)

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем так, добавил структуру к вопросу.

Comment: @TehD А БД какая?

Comment: postgresql стоит

Comment: @TehD Правильно ли я понимаю, что в `groups` нет дубликатов? Т.е. если заказчик связан с фирмой, то для этой связи будет только одна запись в таблице?

Comment: Да, все записи (по двум колонкам) уникальны.

Comment: @TehD Но в чём тогда смысл запроса? Не будут ли в одной строке совмещены тёплое с мягким? Если выбирать наиболее активного заказчика, то для него каждая фирма имеет ровно одно вхождение в `groups`, и непонятно, что максимизировать по фирмам. Если в первом столбце выбрать фирму, имеющую наибольшее количество представителей-заказчиков, то она может не иметь никакого отношения к заказчику, который стоит с ней в одной строке. Это можно сделать, но так ли задумывалось?

Comment: @TehD проблема в том,про что каждый заказчик относится к любой из фирм не чаще одного раза: либо относится, либо нет. В этих таблицах просто нет информации о частоте контактов

Comment: А я думал что я что-то не понимаю. Я к этому же пришел и ничего не понял. Значит нужно менять схему. Спасибо Вам!